# how to install kivy when dependencies give error

Tags: pip

I am working on windows 10 and installed python 3.9.
I tried to download kivy but getting this error

***ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement kivy_deps.sdl2==0.1.* (from versions: 0.3.0, 0.3.1)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for kivy_deps.sdl2==0.1.****

if the person or programmer is reading this and knows the solution please tell me

Answer (score 0):

As kivy.org states, nowadays, latest(by the time of posting == 1.11.0) version supports only 2.7, 3.5 and 3.7 versions of python.

So please, use python 3.7 for kivy.

For windows, you need to install additional packages (gstreamer, etc.) for kivy to operate successfully.

```
python -m pip install docutils pygments pypiwin32 kivy_deps.sdl2==0.1.* kivy_deps.glew==0.1.* 
python -m pip install kivy_deps.gstreamer==0.1.*
```

Source to check: https://kivy.org/doc/stable/installation/installation-windows.html

Cheers